# Pre-processing image using opencv for tesseract

Tags: opencv, xamarin, xamarin.android, ocr, emgucv

I want to know the methods needed to process an image for the best results, before giving it to OCR. Also, what character set should be provided to get the best result. Currently, I am working on an Xamarin Android App.

Below is my image processing code.

```
 CvInvoke.CvtColor(img, img, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
 //CvInvoke.Canny(gray, canny, 100, 50, 3, false);
 Size s = new Size(3, 3);
 CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(img, img, s, 0, 0, BorderType.Default);
 //CvInvoke.FastNlMeansDenoising(img, img, 3, 7, 21);
 CvInvoke.AdaptiveThreshold(img, img, 255, AdaptiveThresholdType.MeanC, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary, 5, 4);
 CvInvoke.Threshold(img, img, 0, 255,  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Otsu);
```

I am using the EmguCv library for processing, as well as Tesseract.

Below is my white listed character set.

```
_ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-1234567890 :$/.?,!@#%^&*()_+=\'\";{}[]+");
```

I want to scan receipt and I am very new to this concept. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Improved code formatting. Improved grammar. Changed title to be more descriptive of question.

Comment: Image processing is very image dependent. Do you have any sample images?